# Filehelpers fixed size records can it ignore a single extra space/line-ending in some files?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

Using [FileHelpers](https://www.filehelpers.net/) FixedFileEngine to read in large files from customers. One customer seems to have an extra whitespace per record (perhaps lf/cf TBD).

BUT can I support this difference easily in the parsing record definition?

```
[FixedLengthRecord()]
public class ClaimEntryDch
{
  ...
  [IgnoreOptionalWhitespace(1)] // something like this?
  string IgnoreThis { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for the [`[FieldOptional]`](https://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/T_FileHelpers_FieldOptionalAttribute.htm) attribute?

```
[FixedLengthRecord()]
public class ClaimEntryDch
{
    ...
    [FieldFixedLength(1)]
    [FieldOptional]
    string IgnoreThis { get; set; }
}
```

See this [example fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MlyREi) for a demonstration.

Comment: that didn't work for me, but it helped by doing that the exception pointed the way using FixedMode.AllowLessChars.

[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowLessChars)]
public class ClaimEntryCenter

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own Xerillo's answer pointed the way by creating an exception that gave me the eventual answer using FixedMode.AllowLessChars.

```
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowLessChars)]
public class ClaimEntryCenter
```